# Is my ADSL modem/router dead? Can it be fixed?

Tags: router

I have a [Billion BiPAC 6404VGP R3 VoIP ADSL Modem/Router](http://au.billion.com/products/voip/firmware/bipac6404vgpr3.html) router and when I went to go turn it on this morning only the power phone1 and Internet LEDs lit up even though I had 3 LAN cables plugged in and no phone lines plugged in

I’ve tried hard resetting it, unplugged everything from the back gave it about 5 mins before powering it back on with just the power cable plugged in and similar variants but it always powers on with the power phone1 and Internet LEDs lit.

Does anyone know if this can be fixed?

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually asked a question so that we had some idea of what kind of answer you wanted.

Comment: Also, have you tried the [recovery utility](http://au.billion.com/products/3g-adsl2+/firmware/bipac6404vp.html) yet, or pushing firmware to it using tftp?

Comment: I should clarify that I have no network access to the router and I have no internet access (I'm on my phone)

Comment: Is it an ISP supplied (owned) router? If so call your ISP. They should replace it free of charge.

Comment: It was an ISP router but I had had it for longer than the warranty lasted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling my ISP and they said that because the power light was staying orange when powering it on that it was dead

Went and bought a Asus DSL N55U and I'm back up running with internet

Answer (score 0):

You can try flashing the BIOS of the router though this is not an easy task. It sounds to me like it's finished anyway + you can pick a new router up for next to nothing cost now.